# Emulating Page Navigation in Telerik Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I am trying to find the best way to implement wpf like navigation in my telerik winforms app.

I need to have a fixed navigation bar and selecting different links in that bar opens different screen. This is a large application so I can't simply use panels or page views. I must have independent screens that are loaded and displayed in a fixed part of the main screen. something like Ms Outlook where selecting different options on the navigation pane opens different parts of the application on the same screen.

Please help with the best approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create user controls for the different views and place them in some sort of a container (the fixed part in the main screen).